# import PySide vs. ImportError: No module named 'PySide'

Tags: python, pyside, python-import, cx-freeze

When I type:

```
username:~/Desktop/folder$ python
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, May 28 2015, 17:04:42) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> import PySide
```

PySide is successfully imported (since I already did `brew install pyside` beforehand).  In other words, no errors were produced when importing PySide.  However, when I try to run a PySide-dependent GUI (by double clicking it), I get:

```
ImportError: No module named 'PySide'
```

I have a feeling that this has something to do with my Python path (which up top is from Anaconda), whereas my PySide is installed here: `/usr/local/Cellar`.

How can I get rid of the `ImportError: No module named 'PySide'` when launching my executable?

**EDIT:**

Here is the cx_Freeze setup file used to compile the GUI:

```
# A simple setup script to create an executable using PyQt4. This also
# demonstrates the method for creating a Windows executable that does not have
# an associated console.
#
# PyQt4app.py is a very simple type of PyQt4 application
#
# Run the build process by running the command 'python setup.py build'
#
# If everything works well you should find a subdirectory in the build
# subdirectory that contains the files needed to run the application

application_title = "MY_GUI" #what you want to application to be called
main_python_file = "GUI.py" #the name of the python file you use to run the program

import sys

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

includes = ["atexit","re"]

setup(
        name = application_title,
        version = "0.1",
        description = "Sample cx_Freeze PyQt4 script",
        options = {"build_exe" : {"includes" : includes }},
        executables = [Executable(main_python_file, base = base)])
```

Comment: Where did you get the executable?

Comment: Successfully compiled it myself from src using cx_Freeze.

Comment: OK, that information is very important. Please include the `cx_freeze` setup information in your question. We can't read your mind.

Comment: No problem, one moment.

Comment: Just from a first glance, you didn't put PySide in `includes`.

Comment: Good catch!  Is this good: `options = {"build_exe" : {"includes" : includes pyside }}` or should it be `PySide` (caps-dependent)?

Comment: Still same error: `ImportError: No module named 'PySide'` when I use `options = {"build_exe" : {"includes" : includes pyside}}`

Comment: I suggest reading through the `cx_freeze` [documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). Your variable `includes` should be a list of *every single* module you import in your code, with the capitalization used in your code.

Comment: Ok let me try that and I will update this question with an Update section once I'm done.  Thank you for your helpful suggestions.